# Using EEPROM to write a counter value

Tags: c++, c, eeprom

I have made a program that increments a counter everytime the up button is pressed. I am trying to write this value to EEPROM, so that when I turn my board off and on again, the value before power off is shown on screen.

I wrote this code but the value doesn't seem to be written to EEPROM. The counter incrementation works fine.

```
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <Adafruit_RGBLCDShield.h>
#include <utility/Adafruit_MCP23017.h>
Adafruit_RGBLCDShield lcd = Adafruit_RGBLCDShield();

int addr = 0;
byte value;

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
}

int a;  
void loop() {
  uint8_t buttons = lcd.readButtons();
  if (buttons) {

    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);

    if (buttons & BUTTON_UP) {
      a+= 1;
      EEPROM.write(addr, a);
      value = EEPROM.read(addr);
      lcd.print(value);
      delay(100);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The only time you read the EEPROM is right after writing it, which is pointless. You need to `EEPROM.read()` in `setup()` if you want the value restored at boot time.

Comment: That did the trick. Appreciate it man!

Comment: Also you only want one value to store the counter in, not two. Either `a` or `value` - take your pick.

Comment: The EEPROM.read and EEPROM.write read and write only a single byte. You can use EEPROM.put and EEPROM.get to read and write an (unsigned) int or a (unsigned) long.

Comment: I see you always use address 0, since EEPROM has a limited write life (like 10K or so), maybe it's best to use difference addresses. 10K presses is a lot, but not unrealistic over a long time probably.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers: The EEPROM is rated for 100K write cycles.

Comment: My normal EEPROM method is to set a variable to the desired value, along with a timestamp variable. Reset the timestamp variable every time the button is pressed. Then when a certain time has elapsed since the last press write the value to EEPROM. That way if you press the button 50 times in quick succession you only get one write to EEPROM. A couple of seconds delay on the write works well.

Answer (score 1):

just add `a = EEPROM.read(addr);` in your setup
also, you can remove `byte value` and use `a` you wrote to memory in the previous line